# Which folder does ionic files should be placed www or src?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using latest ionic framework and very new to ionic! I find src and www folder in ionic project structure! I am confused that where should i place my files? When i searched many forum shows that it should be in **src**, While i used Ionic creative studio to test a design and on downloading the zip files they ask to place it in **www** folder.

I am confused here! Please help me in this!

Answer (score 0):

Your own files should go in `src`.

The files ionic generates on build are placed inside `www/build`

In your source folder you can choose your own structure i normally do something like:

```
src/app/app.module etc
src/pages/nameOfPage/files
src/services/files
```

If you have any questions feel free to ask

Comment: So where should i place my html, css and JS files?

Comment: not really.. even the assets go to src/assets. they get copied to www from there

Comment: When i created a blank ionic project all app.js,controllers.js,directive.js,routes.jsetc are in www/js folder

Comment: @KarthikCP are you talking about ionic v1 or ionic 2/3?

Comment: I hope these are files where we should add angular functions

Comment: All the angular functions,controllers etc are now added in app.module right?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using Ionic v1. In Ionic v1 you mainly  work in www folder where you html templates,js file for controller,app,service etc present.
In ionic v2 src folder is used for development.

Comment: No I am using version 3.15.1! There is both www and src folder

Comment: I think that is the version number of the Ionic CLI, which is different from the version number of Ionic's library.

Comment: if you are using v2 or v3 then you don't need to worry about www folder..Your development folder is src.In src folder you can add your html page typescript file,SCSS file etc..